# Probability Calculation: Calculate the probability that a woman makes sport / man makes sport..

Tags: probability, probability-theory

*This problem is from an old exam which can be found here (in German): https://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/~koessler/MathematikInformatiker/KlausurB.pdf (Aufgabe 4). I'm asking it here because I'm preparing for an exam and I'd like to know the correct solution.*

> There is a company where $60$% of women and $80$% of men take up a sport.
>   The number of male and female employees is $3:2$ ("3 to 2").
>
> 1. What's the probability that an employee takes up a sport?
> 2. What is the probability that an employee who is doing sports is female?
>
> *(If someone is interested, you get 9 / 100 credits for this problem.)*

I'm totally bad at this  topic (probability calculation) but I surely gave it a try at least.

> 1.

So for women who take up a sport we have $60$%, I prefer to write it as $0.6$. For men we have $80$%, so $0.8$. The ratio / proportion / however it's called is $3:2$.

Now I'm calculating it like this: $0.6 \cdot \frac{2}{5}+ 0.8 \cdot \frac{3}{5} = 0.72$

So $72$% of all employees take up a sport. Is that result realistic?  Looking at the initial conditions it seems realistic to me. However I couldn't tell why I calculated it like that and I'm not even sure if it's correct :s

> 2.

Assuming 1. is correct, $72$% of all employees take up a sport, so $28$% of all employees don't do sport. We are looking for the probability that a female employee that takes up a sport, hmm.. I would do $$\frac{0.6 \cdot \frac{2}{5}}{0.72} = \frac{1}{3} \approx 33.3\text{%}$$

Again I cannot explain my approach :o

Comment: 1 looks right but for 2 should it not be 60% or am I being tired?

Comment: @mathreadler i think OP needs a probability that a random employee happens to be a woman that works out -- otherwise it is given away in the problem itself

Comment: I think the 2. question should be: "What is the probability that an employee who is doing sports is female?"

Comment: @dromastyx Yes this is right, sorry my English : /

Comment: @mathreadler I editted my question, I translated the second question wrong :p

Comment: @gt6989b I agree that sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your answers are absolutely correct. You computed the results using [the law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) and [Bayes. theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem).

A quick verification of your results is given below. Suppose there are $100$ employees in the company. So $60$ of them are men, and women are $40$ in number. Also, $48$ men and $24$ do the sports. So a total of $72$ out of $100$ employees do the sports. Hence, the answer of the first question is correct: $72/100=0.72$.

For the second part, you want to compute the probability of the female employee who do the sports among the $72$ employees. Since there are $24$ female employees who do the sports, the answer to the second part is $24/72=1/3$.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this seems correct $0.6 \cdot \frac{2}{5}+ 0.8 \cdot \frac{3}{5} = 0.72$

But for women you proceed this way $$\frac{0.6 \cdot \frac{2}{5}}{0.72} = \frac{1}{3} \approx 33.3\text{%}$$
Everyhing is correct. Sorry